# Spring cloud consul config

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-consul

I am trying to write a custom configuration for spring cloud consul config. 
I was able to make the application work with autoconfiguration.
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-consul/multi/multi_spring-cloud-consul-config.html

I just need to manually define the required beans for doing the same.
Can someone help me in understanding required beans/configuration for making this work.

Following autoconfiguration classes are already found. Some how after that also i was not able to make it work.

- ConsulAutoConfiguration
- ConsulConfigAutoconfiguration
- ConsulBootstrapConfiguration
- ConsulBinderConfiguration